# How to perform a range query in elastic search with java Hight level rest client?

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi Currently I am having an elastic search index and i am trying to perform a date range query on the documents within that index using java high level rest client library . However it doesn't work as expected. so the following is my index .I have to perform a range query on the field @timestamp.

```
{
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "successful" : 2,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 229081,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "mep-reports-2019.09.11",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "68e8e03f-baf8-4bfc-a920-58e26edf835c-353899837500",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "account_id" : "270d13e6-2f4f-4d51-99d5-92ffba5f0cb6",
          "inventory" : "SMS",
          "flight_name" : "test flight 001",
          "status" : "ENROUTE",
          "msg_text" : "Test !!!!!!!!!!!!!!1 elastic search:is.gd/YfzotY",
          "flight_id" : "68e8e03f-baf8-4bfc-a920-58e26edf835c",
          "submission_ts" : "1568197286",
          "recipient" : "353899837500",
          "o_error" : null,
          "nof_segments" : "-1",
          "campaign_id" : "0fae8662-bee9-46ac-9b3e-062f4ba55966",
          "campaign_name" : "Index search petri11",
          "@version" : "1",
          "sender" : "800111",
          "delivery_ts" : "0",
          "@timestamp" : "2019-09-11T10:21:26.000Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "mep-reports-2019.09.11",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "68e8e03f-baf8-4bfc-a920-58e26edf835c-353899837503",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "account_id" : "270d13e6-2f4f-4d51-99d5-92ffba5f0cb6",
          "inventory" : "SMS",
          "flight_name" : "test flight 001",
          "status" : "ENROUTE",
          "msg_text" : "Test !!!!!!!!!!!!!!1 elastic searchh",
          "flight_id" : "68e8e03f-baf8-4bfc-a920-58e26edf835c",
          "submission_ts" : "1568197286",
          "recipient" : "353899837503",
          "o_error" : null,
          "nof_segments" : "-1",
          "campaign_id" : "0fae8662-bee9-46ac-9b3e-062f4ba55966",
          "campaign_name" : "Index search petri11",
          "@version" : "1",
          "sender" : "800111",
          "delivery_ts" : "0",
          "@timestamp" : "2019-09-11T10:21:26.000Z"
        }
      }
}
```

the followign is my java code that tries to do a range query on the @timestamp and it doesnt work . I am only pasting a part of the range query snippet below from my builder class named SearchRequestBuilder.

```
SearchRequestBuilder range(ZonedDateTime startDate, ZonedDateTime endDate) {

    System.out.println(startDate); // 2019-08-31T23:00Z
    System.out.println(endDate);   // 2019-09-17T13:25:18.154Z



    RangeQueryBuilder startRangeQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@timestamp").gte(startDate);
    startRangeQueryBuilder.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

    boolQueryBuilder.should(startRangeQueryBuilder);

    RangeQueryBuilder endRangeQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@timestamp").lte(endDate);
    boolQueryBuilder.should(endRangeQueryBuilder);
    endRangeQueryBuilder.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

    return this;
}
```

any idea how can i fix my range query to in order to work it correctly

```
the followign is a SearchRequestBuilder that builds an elastic search index

static class SearchRequestBuilder {

        private SearchRequest searchRequest;

        private SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder;

        private BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder;

        SearchRequestBuilder(String elasticSearchIndex) {
            this.searchRequest = new SearchRequest(elasticSearchIndex);
            this.searchRequest.indicesOptions(IndicesOptions.lenientExpandOpen());
            this.searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
            this.searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
            this.boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
            this.searchSourceBuilder.query(this.boolQueryBuilder);
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder from(Integer pageNumber) {
            this.searchSourceBuilder.from(pageNumber);
            return this;
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder size(Integer pageSize) {
            this.searchSourceBuilder.size(pageSize);
            return this;
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder timeOut(long duration, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
            this.searchSourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(duration, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
            return this;
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder range(ZonedDateTime startDate, ZonedDateTime endDate) {

            System.out.println(startDate);
            System.out.println(endDate);
        //  this.boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@timestamp").from(startDate,true).to(endDate));

            //QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("FieldName").from(startDate,true).to(endDate));


            RangeQueryBuilder startRangeQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@timestamp").gte(startDate);
            startRangeQueryBuilder.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");

            boolQueryBuilder.should(startRangeQueryBuilder);

            RangeQueryBuilder endRangeQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("@timestamp").lte(endDate);
            boolQueryBuilder.should(endRangeQueryBuilder);
            endRangeQueryBuilder.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");



            return this;
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder msisdn(String msisdn) {
            if (msisdn != null) {
                if (msisdn.indexOf("*") >= 0) {
                    WildcardQueryBuilder msisdnWildCardQueryBuilder = new WildcardQueryBuilder("recipient", msisdn);
                    boolQueryBuilder.must(msisdnWildCardQueryBuilder);
                } else {
                    MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("recipient", msisdn);
                    boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
                }
            }
            return this;
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder accountId(UUID accountId) {
            if (accountId != null) {
                MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("account_id", accountId.toString());
                boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
            }
            return this;
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder campaignId(UUID campaignId) {
            if (campaignId != null) {
                MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("campaign_id", campaignId.toString());
                boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
            }
            return this;
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder flightId(UUID flightId) {
            if (flightId != null) {
                MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("flight_id", flightId.toString());
                boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
            }
            return this;
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder cdrStatus(String cdrStatus) {
            if (cdrStatus != null) {
                MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("status", cdrStatus);
                boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
            }
            return this;
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder inventoryCode(String inventoryCode) {
            if (inventoryCode != null) {
                MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("inventory", inventoryCode);
                boolQueryBuilder.must(matchQueryBuilder);
            }
            return this;
        }

        SearchRequestBuilder sort() {
            searchSourceBuilder.sort(new FieldSortBuilder("@timestamp").order(SortOrder.DESC));
            return this;
        }

        SearchRequest build() {
            return this.searchRequest;
        }

    }
```

thank you so much

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "it doesnt work"? Does it yield an error? Does it return wrong documents? Does it not return the right ones?

Comment: in short the  the range query on the @timestamp fields are getting ignored. it returns all documents irrespective of the range dates (ZonedDateTime startDate, ZonedDateTime endDate) entered.

Comment: Where does `boolQueryBuilder` come from and how is it used? You probably need to show a bit more code.

Comment: sure i am using a request builder class updated in the description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that the `should()` clauses are not taken into account because the other clauses are `must()` ([See why here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)). If you use `filter()` clauses instead of `must()` then it will work.

Example with the `flightId` method follows:

```
    SearchRequestBuilder flightId(UUID flightId) {
        if (flightId != null) {
            MatchQueryBuilder matchQueryBuilder = new MatchQueryBuilder("flight_id", flightId.toString());
            boolQueryBuilder.filter(matchQueryBuilder);
        }                       ^
        return this;            |
    }                           |
                           change this
```